# Trying to place an image in col-md-6, centred when viewed on phone

Tags: html, css, responsive

What is the best practice way of placing an image in a bootstrap `col-md-6` so it is centered but only when viewed on a phone?

I'm trying to do this in a `queries.css` file but I'm stuck.

Also, Am I supposed to link the site or quote code I'm working on here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    

<title>nalexanderdev.com</title>
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">  
<link href="css/queries.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="icon"
      type="image/jpg"
      href="img/profile5.jpeg" />
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="containerNavbar">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">nalexanderdev.com</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Home</h3></section><br>
            <p>I am a student at National College of Ireland studying Science in Computing: Software Development. In my spare time I make websites.apps using different coding languages.</p>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  Latest Completed Project:
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <a  href="http://176.32.230.46/omnifoodproject.com/index.php" target="_blank">Project: Omnifood</a></br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
            <div id="wrapper" style="width:100%; text-align:right">
            <img class="profile" src="img/profile5.jpeg" alt="profile5"/>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                  Bootstrap Projects:
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="http://176.32.230.51/theblog.com/" target="_blank">Project: The Blog</a></br>
                <a href="http://176.32.230.53/businesstheme.com/" target="_blank">Project: Business Theme</a></br>
                <a href="http://176.32.230.52/ecommercetemplate.com/" target="_blank">Project: Ecommerce Template Using LESS</a></br>
                <a href="http://176.32.230.53/edxco.com/" target="_blank">Project: Company Website</a></br>
                <a href="http://176.32.230.52/cmsadminproject.com/login.html" target="_blank">Project: CMS Admin</a></br>
                <a href="http://176.32.230.52/photogallery.com/" target="_blank">Project: Photo Gallery</a></br>
                <a href="http://176.32.230.51/dobblesocialmediasite.com/" target="_blank">Project: Social Media Site</a></br>
                <a href="http://176.32.230.50/fotoshareappproject.com/" target="_blank">Project: Photo Share App</a></br>
                <a href="http://176.32.230.50/agencylandingpage.com/" target="_blank">Project: Agency Landing Page Using LESS</a></br>
                <a href="http://176.32.230.52/sassresumepage.com/" target="_blank">Project: Resume Page using SASS</a></br>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                  Web Dev Projects:
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
              <div class="panel-body">
                        <a href="http://176.32.230.50/mymobileapp.com/" target="_blank">Project: My Mobile App(c 2013)</a></br>
                        <a href="http://217.199.187.190/postcodeproject.com/" target="_blank">Project: Postcode Finder</a></br>
                        <a href="http://79.170.44.219/nalexanderdev.com/php/index.php?" target="_blank">Project: Weather Forecast</a></br>
                        <a href="http://www.nalexanderdev.com/wordpress/" target="_blank">Project: Wordpress</a></br>
                        <a href="http://217.199.187.195/landingpageproject.com/" target="_blank">Project: Landing Page</a></br>
                        <a href="http://176.32.230.47/playcodeplayer.com/" target="_blank">Project: CodePlayer</a></br>
                        <a href="http://176.32.230.46/omnifoodproject.com/" target="_blank">Project: Omnifood</a></br>
                        <a href="http://176.32.230.8/nicksthfcsite.com/" target="_blank">Project: THFC site</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
                  Games:
                </a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <a href="http://176.32.230.49/reactionstester.com/" target="_blank">Reactions tester</a></br>
                <a href="http://79.170.40.170/nickalexandershowmanyfingers.com/" target="_blank">How many fingers?</a><br/>
                <a href="http://176.32.230.8/nicksproject1.com/" target="_blank">Javascript circle</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, please add your CSS & html.

Comment: please show the code

Comment: You should include relevant code with your post.

Comment: Thanks to all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `md` means medium, which is the display used mainly for tablets and netbooks. As well as `col-md-6` on both of your divs, add a `col-xs-6. This is the Extra Small column and works on Phones. For future reference, please add all code and relevant information.

Comment: Thanks xs-6 was great idea, it aligns left though haha http://176.32.230.50/nalexanderdev.ie/index.html